# What did God mean when He said Let us make men in our own image?

Tags: genesis, revelation, creation

What did God mean when He said Let us make men in our image, which can be found in genesis...

Comment: This one also expounds the meaning of that verse: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/did-god-make-an-idol?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question: What did God mean when He said Let us make men in our image, which can be found in genesis

Genesis 1:26-27 was translated on the premise that the Hebrew word Elohim translated to God is a plural form. Bible use of that word indicates Elohim is a word of high deference when used in reference to YaHavah and Jesus and in a lesser degree for human leadership. Replacing the plurality with deference reveals a clear meaning for the verses in question. The Word of YHVH Bible--Feed My Sheep Version replaced LORD and God with the original Hebrew name of YHVH and God with Elohim. This opens the Scriptures up with astounding clarity and it is in obedience to the command to proclaim the name of YaHavah. I think you will agree when you read the Word of YHVH version of the verses in question included below. In the King James Version (KJV) the plurality of verse 26 does not agree with the singularity of verse 27. There is no us, we, or our for YaHavah in the Bible.

26—And Elohim said, [I will] make man [in the] image, [of my] likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creeps upon the earth. 27—So Elohim created man [in his] image, in the image of Elohim created he him; male and female created he them. (Genesis 1:26-27)

I hope this was helpful.